# Install penetration tool on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, installation

How to install penetration tool on my Ubuntu 11.10 from Blackbuntu or Backtrack source and fugure out it's work or not.thank for helping

Answer (score 1):

Blackbuntu is a distribution changing quite a lot of ubuntu. But you can look to their tool list to see what packages they are using:
http://www.blackbuntu.com/tools-list

After you see a tool you are interested to, google it - e,g, "ubuntu install httprint".

Another way of using Blackbuntu is to install virtualbox and run a blackbuntu instance within a virtual pc. That would keep your daily working ubuntu installation clean.

Comment: > i agree with you...its better to install on vm.. last time i have installed aircrack package on ubuntu ... it was not working properly as it is working on vm .. . so i think if u have some old pc install blackbuntu or backtrack on it ...then it will work much better then vm ... this all been tested 4 to 5 times (installing vm & as host os )